# Keyboard only dims when system shutdown is attempted

Tags: keyboard, shutdown

I am fairly new to Ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver) 64-bit. My system's processor is an Intel® Core™ i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 with 16 gig RAM. I am mentioning the keyboard because that is what revealed the following problem. The keyboard is an Azio with backlit keys.

The system shutdown normally until last night. When I shut the system down it would power off and everything would be off. Now when I power off the system acts like it is powering off but the keyboard now goes dim but not off like before. The only changes are I installed Firefox and configured it so I could use the extensions and I added a 7 port USB hub.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a motherboard that has a always on for USB ports?

Comment: It always shutdown normally and I did not change anything in my bios settings. So if I do have that type of motherboard and I did not change the settings in my bios I do not understand how this would make any difference.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I realized that my PC has an always on USB port.

Comment: Is the 7-port-usb-hub powered?   If so, it's possible that the usb-hub is sending power to your pc usb ports which is allowing your 'usb-keyboard' to glow dimly  (I'm betting keyboard is usb right!?).  I suspect if you disconnect the usb-hub cable from your pc, the keyboard leds will go out??, ie. the issue is the 'new' usb-hub's power not turning off... *this is pure guess, but isn't related to Ubuntu*

Comment: singrium was right, I tried that and it worked. I shutdown after I disconnected the usb hub and it shutdown with no problems...  THANKS

Comment: I am a newbie to this... I may have indicated the wrong user as completed. I do not know how to mark the question answered or completed...  but the issue is fixed

Comment: @budd-newbie Please post your solution as an answer below by clicking the '*Answer your question*' button. It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [self-answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). Then you would be able to "accept" the answer after a couple of days to indicate the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> I shutdown after I disconnected the USB hub and it shutdown with no problems.

Source: [comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160689/shut-down-problem#comment1933232_1160689)